# How to make items in a grid fit in one row?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying make 3 divs fit inside a grid. However I'd like to reuse the code for other grids where there can be more than one grid. Is this possible or should I write the code separately?

```
  <div class="div-wrapper">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
  </div>

.div-wrapper{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-gap:5px;
  width:100%;
  height:10vh;
  background:black;
}
```

However, I'd like to use the above code other wrappers with more than 3 divs inside such as

```
    <div class="div-wrapper">
      <div class="div1"></div>
      <div class="div2"></div>
      <div class="div3"></div>
      <div class="div4"></div>
      <div class="div5"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can consider  flexbox and you will easily do this

Comment: The thing with CSS grids is that the number of columns is fixed. In your case, you have declared 3 columns but have 5 elements, so the last 2 will not fit in the grid at all. If you want a flexible layout solution, you should be looking at flexbox instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Then don't say you have 3 columns.

You can just use `grid-auto-flow` like this:

```
.div-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

Then it will behave like `flex` and you can have auto number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between my-flex-container">
  <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">3</div>
</div>


<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between my-flex-container">
  <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">3</div>
  <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">4</div>
  <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">5</div>
</div>
```

Use bootstrap flex columns 
more refer here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between my-flex-container">
     <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">1</div>
     <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">2</div>
     <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">3</div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between my-flex-container">
     <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">1</div>
     <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">2</div>
     <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">3</div>
     <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">4</div>
     <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BootStrap "row" class refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
       <div class="p-2">one</div>
       <div class="p-2">two</div>
       <div class="p-2">three</div>
</div>
```

This will show in row.